# Can you run wordpress with multiple domains at the same time (not multisite)?

Tags: domain

Every now and then some clients have multiple domains for the same site. For example domain.com and domain.org. Is it possible to have wordpress work with both domains at the same time? I typically see issues when trying to load resources because of Cross-domain access. I know that I could just point domain.com to domain.org in the domain settings, but I was wondering if that's the only way.

I searched for solutions here, but all questions are about how to setup multiple domains for multisites (which makes sense). Just to be clear, I am not running a multisite.

Comment: What you're asking about is called domain mapping, where a site has many alias' e.g. tomjn.com tomjn.co.uk tomjn.org all being the same website. However it would be simpler and more efficient to declare 1 domain canonical, and have the others redirect there, this simplifies login authentication and cookie setup, as well as issues with canonical locations of content and SEO

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Are you wanting for the exact same WordPress site to work on two different domain names, where all links and content would use either domain name?

If this were the case, you would run into [Duplicate Content issues with Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en), hurting your SEO pretty badly.

That being said, you still would have a very hard time getting WordPress to properly load your content off of either domain name. A variety of functionality uses the [get_site_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_url) function to construct the links on your pages, so all of your links would be using only the one domain within your Siteurl setting.

Even still, if you want to try and get really tricksy, you can use something like the following to define your Siteurl and Home in the wp-config.php based upon the Domain being passed to the site:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/path/to/wordpress');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/path/to/wordpress');
```

Comment: That's pretty much the answer I expected. Thank you.

Comment: does not work,, whatever i do if i browse to any domain added , i will get redirect to the original domain name

Comment: Seems like this solution is no longer working. I tried the same but couldn't get it working. While it used to work with previous version of WP.

Comment: It is working for me on the latest WP version 5.6.1. Thank you so much.

Comment: Trying this today on an up to date WordPress install, I needed to make sure to put these definitions at the top of my config file. When placed at the bottom of config some portions of the template run before the setting gets defined.

Comment: Maybe this official guide can be used for what the OP is trying to do: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/running-a-development-copy-of-wordpress/

Answer (score 5):

Just check this **WordPress Plugin** it should resolve this issue easy way..

### https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domain/

Comment: Can you offer an explanation as to why this plugin is a better solution that something custom built for this user's specific site.  Just posting links isn't very helpful and isn't teaching anyone anything.

Comment: @TonyDjukic that plugin also replace URL in post content, media's URL. Changing WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME base on  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] will not do this.